# Ionic @HostListener is duplicating each time i open

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im using ionic 4.4.0.

Host listener should open and close with my page, but sometimes, i close the page and open it again and i get two host listener instances.

Please help.
Tthis is the way im calling hostListener:

```
 @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
      handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    //your code here
 }
```

Comment: This is directive, right?

Comment: yes, this code is inside my class declaration

Comment: where you apply this directive?

Comment: this code is inside an ionic page main class, I push the page to my view using NavController